# Change logo on mouseover in wordpress

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, mouseover, graphical-logo

OK,
so what i want to do is to get my logo changed on mouseover.
If the default logo is default.PNG i want to change it to new.PNG when you hover over it with the mouse!

I am looking for the best solution,that is compatible with IE as well.I have tried a lot to get this working with :hover in CSS,but couldn't make it,so please assist.

This is how my header.php file looks like:

```
<!--Logo-->
        <div class="grid_3_no_margin"> 
            <a href="<?php echo site_url() ?>">
                <?php if(!empty($al_options['al_logo'])):?>
                    <img src="<?php echo $al_options['al_logo']?>" alt="<?php echo $al_options['al_logotext']?>" id="logo-image" class="logo" />
                <?php else:?>
                    <?php echo isset($al_options['al_logotext']) ? $al_options['al_logotext'] : 'Balance' ?>
                <?php endif?>
            </a>
        </div>
        <!--End Logo-->
```

And this is what i am getting when i analyze the actual logo element using a plugin for firefox:

```
<div class="grid_3_no_margin"> 
    <a href="http://myurl.com">
      <img src="http://myurl.com/icons/logo.PNG" alt="Logo" id="logo-image" class="logo">
    </a>
</div>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use javascript if you want to change the img or the img source.

You can achieve the same result in css by using background-image property :

```
.img-div {
    background-image: url('logo.png');
    height : <logo-height>
    width : <logo-width>
}

.img-div:hover {
    background-image: url('logo2.png');
}
```

instead of `<img />`, set `<div class="img-div"></div>`

but you'll probably have to set a height and width to the div, supposing you already know them (to replace in  and  respectively.

- This is cross-browser, no problem about that.
- This is lighter than doing it in JS, and you don't have loading issues since the logo2.png will be loaded anyway when the CSS is parsed.

Comment: So,
you mean creating something like this:
     <div class="img-div"><img src=<?php echo $al_options['al_logo']?> alt="<?php echo $al_options['al_logotext']?>" id="logo-image" class="logo" /></div>

I did this,but it didn't work.

Comment: Anyways,i fixed it with JavaScript!
Thanks for assistance!

Comment: That is the most ideal case Augustin. No need to run scripts for something this simple that could be implemented by CSS. I gave you an upvote. :)